# Velostrata Migration from On-premises to GCP. Error log: echo boot failed and waiting for disks online. Migrated VM Rolled-back to on-prem from GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration

I am seeing the errors in the log: echo boot failed and waiting for disks online in the console log of Velostrata Manager while I am doing the migration of a windows 2016 VM (No Symantec End Point Protection) from on-premises vcenter to Google Cloud Platform. Below is the error log for a quick reference. Answers are welcome and much appreciated. I am trying for the resolution from one day, but no luck. Thank you.

```
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:24:36.874Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:24:38.937Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:24:40.968Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:24:43.015Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:24:45.062Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:24:47.093Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:24:49.140Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:24:51.187Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:24:53.218Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6}
2019/11/27 07:24:55.265Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:24:57.312Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:24:59.343Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:25:01.390Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
2019/11/27 07:25:03.437Z Waiting for disks to be available... 
2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} ============================ port: 2 ============================ 2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} ============================ port: 3 ============================ 2019-11-27 07:28:51.623 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} 
============================ port: 4 ============================ 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.405 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} #!ipxe 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.405 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} # iqn:iqn.2014-05.com.velostrata.iscsi.base:vlst-6 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.405 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} # ip1:10.120.22.11 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.405 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} # ip2:10.120.22.12 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} # token:haeth2vp 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} # mode:normal 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} # boot:bios 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} :setenv 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} set syslog 10.120.22.11 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} route 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} set net0/hostname vlsboot 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} set initiator-iqn iqn.2014-05.com.velostrata.int.haeth2vp:vlst-6 2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} set tgt1 iscsi:10.120.22.11 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} set tgt2 iscsi:10.120.22.12 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} set iqn iqn.2014-05.com.velostrata.iscsi.base:vlst-6 2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} echo Initiator IQN ${initiator-iqn} 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} echo Target root path ${tgt1}::::${iqn} 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} echo Target replica path ${tgt2}::::${iqn} 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} :hookretry 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} inc hook-attempt 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} echo Hook attempt ${hook-attempt} at ${unixtimestr} 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} clear hook-error 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} isset ${drive1} || sanhook --drive 0x81 --no-describe ${tgt1}:::1:${iqn} ${tgt2}:::1:${iqn} && inc drive1 || inc hook-error 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53,step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} isset ${hook-error} || goto bootretry 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} iseq ${hook-attempt} 25 && goto end || sleep 10 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} goto hookretry 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} :bootretry 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} inc boot-attempt 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} echo Boot attempt ${boot-attempt} at ${unixtimestr} 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} sanboot ${tgt1}::::${iqn} ${tgt2}::::${iqn} || 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} iseq ${boot-attempt} 25 && goto end || sleep 10 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} goto bootretry 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} :end 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} echo Boot failed 
2019-11-27 07:28:52.406 [tasks-39] DEBUG consoleLogsLogger - {instanceId=projects/gcp-shared-host-nonprod/zones/asia-southeast1-c/instances/vmtestgcp02, originVmName=VMTESTGCP02, parentTaskId=t-53, step=stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-54, vmId=vlst-6} poweroff
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing an Offline Migration?

For Windows 2008 R2, Windows 2012 R1, Windows 2012 R2, Windows 2016 and in 4.5 Windows 2019 Google hasn't supported [offline migration](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.2/reference/supported-os-versions#supported_windows_versions_for_offline_migration).

As today users are  required o manually install the drivers to enable VMs to run in GCP after offline migration. The script below automates this procedure.

There are a couple of known issues in Velostrata 4.0 and 4.2 that could return that error

**Issue**

Cloud instance boot failed (Instance boot was unsuccessful)

**Diagnostic Steps**

1. Collect [Support Bundle](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.2/support/saving-a-support-bundle)
2. Open management-service.log
3. Grep for the following log line:

   2019-04-30 15:49:52.712 [tasks-8] INFO  VSphereServiceGrpcClient - {parentTaskId=t-8, step=stateRollbackRunInCloudTask, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-9} Marking task as failed, taskId: task-25315, reason: Cloud instance boot failed

2019-04-30 {"step":"stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot","task":"RunVmInCloud","taskId":"t-32"},"threadId":246,"threadPriority":5}

**Resolution**

1. Depending on the OS, install [prep package](https://cloud.google.com/velostrata/docs/how-to/prepare-vms-servers/preparing-linux-vms) correctly with its
   dependencies
2. Open Port 3260 (TCP)for iSCSI communication. Cloud Edges connect to
   Migrated VM using port 3260 (iSCSI). This port must be open between
   VM subnet and both Cloud Edges.
3. If source VM is on-premise, backend must be able to resolve FQDN of
   the local ESXi host that the VM is registered with. This is because
   the Backend mounts the VMDK disk files directly. Velostrata Backend
   connects to ESXi host on port 902 (TCP) during disk copy, check that
   this port is open.
4. Open firewall for port 9111 and 443 (TCP)for inbound on the subnet
   which hosts the Velostrata FEs. On-premise backed connects to Cloud
   Edges on port 9111 (TLS). On-premise backed connects to Velostrata
   Manager on port 443 (HTTPS) and 9119 (TCP).

**Root Cause**

Might be various: iSCSI service not reachable, prep package not installed properly, firewall issue.

Comment: I am not performing offline migration. I am using the latest version 4.8

Comment: To fully debug, those error logs are not sufficient. Please collect the support bundle and share errors https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.8/support/saving-a-support-bundle

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the resolution. Yes, the below one resolved my issue.

---

### If source VM is on-premise, backend must be able to resolve FQDN of the local ESXi host that the VM is registered with. This is because the Backend mounts the VMDK disk files directly. Velostrata Backend connects to ESXi host on port 902 (TCP) during disk copy, check that this port is open.

Thanks a lot for your support.